# Make unknown amount of divs fill nicely

Tags: html, css

Now, the title might be a bit vague, but I didn't know any other way to word it. What I basically want is this:

```
---------  ---------  ---------
| DIV 1 |  | DIV 2 |  | DIV 3 |
---------  ---------  ---------
---------  ---------  ---------
| DIV 4 |  | DIV 5 |  | DIV 6 |
---------  ---------  ---------
```

These div's are in a parent with a width of 1000px. So each div is 30% of width (with the proper gap inbetween basically).

The HTML:

```
<div id="matches">
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 1
    </div>
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 2
    </div>
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 3
    </div>
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 4
    </div>
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 5
    </div>
    <div class="match_box">
        DIV 6
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#matches {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

How would I go about doing this? (.match_box being the div that need to flow nicely).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Oriol Well how I worded it in the post. I have all the divs "under" eachother in the code, but I want them to flow like the 1st code block.

Comment: @LJa It's very easy :-) See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to target older browsers, you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This allows you to space the elements nicely. Here they go to the edges on both sides.

```
#matches {
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.match_box {
  width:30%;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ekhts0fs/5/

Changing justify-content to space-between or center (see the link to flexbox above) can position them differently.

Comment: Your JS fiddle is copy of mine.

Comment: @johnc.j. yeah, copied the link from the wrong fiddle. Fixed it now, thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Matsemann This worked almost perfectly, the only problem being they also align out vertically now. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, I just gave the parent the proper height. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#matches {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
}

.match_box {
  width:30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Live:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lu8p6gr3/2/

Comment: I've now got it to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/uJuUNE3.png is there any way to have them spread out to the full width? (the edge is the edge of the green bit) (Updated the link)

Comment: Not to sure I understand you quite well, but my fiddle works fine. You may remove `margin: 5px;` and `padding: 5px` lines, and maybe it helps.

Comment: I am a bit vague, but looking at this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/uJuUNE3.png i want them to spread out, so the right side of the 3rd div, has to touch the right red line, the 2nd div (middle) has to center out between the 2, and the 1st div has to touch the left red line. Any way to achieve this?